# Create a template for the page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-hooks

Let's say I have this implementation of `hook_menu()`:

```
function example_menu(){
    $items = array();

    $items['admin/recent-completions'] = array(
        'title' => 'Recent Completions (Last 100)',
        'page callback' => 'example_recent',
        'access callback' => user_access('Administer content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'weight' => -50
    );

    return $items;
}
```

How can I make a template for the page callback instead of returning a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to implement a [`hook_theme`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) function and specify a template file.

Then in your page callback, you would have to call your theme function.  Something like...

```
function example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'recent_completion' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements', 
      'template' => 'recent-completions',
    ), 
  ...
}

function example_recent() {
  // Do some logic and processing here
  $render_array = array( /* array with parameters for the template */ );
  return theme('recent_completion', $render_array);
}
```

Comment: What's the use of `elements`, `recent_completions`, and `recent_completion` in this context? What's supposed to be the value of `$render_array`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, but wasn't sure how to implement a hook_theme function. [This](http://snipplr.com/view/14456/) is how it's done (in Drupal 6 at least).